# How to enforce security policies when aggregating data from autonomous services?

Tags: architecture, soa

When using request/replay communication it's easy to enforce data security policies since the service owning the data can perform checks for each request - of course this breaks autonomy since it introduces temporal coupling and the services SLAs come to depend on other services.

If using Autonomous Services, a subset of the data pertaining to the authoritative service gets stored in multiple other Autonomous Services that subscribe to relevant events.

How to make sure that the services use and, subsequently publish, the data subset and/or transformations thereof abiding by the original authoritative service's security policies?

One solution I was thinking of was creating a Policy Service but:

- If the Policy Service operates in a request / reply fashion performance will decrease and I might as well use request / reply with the data itself
- If the Policy Service publishes events relevant to policy changes then there must exist code that implements the policy for each and every consumer that operates on data protected by that policy - except from finding a way to distribute the policy (code and rules) as a black-box package for use by all consumers the solution of duplicating the policy enforcing code for all consumers is not appealing to me..

Is there any best practice / recommendation on entity data aggregation whilst enforcing security policies?

Much appreciated!

**UPDATE**
Just to clarify, my problem is that even if the service boundaries are correct, UI composition presents problems since it needs an aggregated data store in order to be able to provide performance sorting and filtering - the IT/Ops service as Udi Dahan calls it. 
The reason for this is that each component from each service only knows about a subset of fields so sorting and filtering cannot be efficiently addressed unless data is aggregated.
If sorting would not have been required, each service component would enforce it's own policies. However, even so, we may find ourselves in a select n+1 situation in some cases, without an aggregated store - I looked at the [Aggregated Reporting Pattern](http://arnon.me/soa-patterns/aggregated-reporting/) as described by Arnon Rotem-Gal-Oz precisely for this situation. It didn't talk about security and I think it implies the duplication of security policies at the Aggregated Reporting Service...

Furthermore, is it even OK to pub/sub sensitive information? Moreover, what you publish is part of the contract but if the policy were to change you wouldn't publish that info anymore - that would change the contract... As I said, req/reply covers this easily...

It's quite possible I'm wrong on all accounts, so I appreciate any thoughts! :-)

Comment: You could likely sign or encrypt each response and then have the key exist on a policy service. The key then expires at a given time and when it does the individual SLAs have to request a new key. Not quite perfect, but it does get you down the right path, I think.

Comment: @JessieA.Morris - That really makes sense! The problem is though that it's not the services themselves that should be restricted from accessing the data but rather the human actors using those services. So the key should probably be assigned for each user.

Comment: @JessieA.Morris (continuation)  I was thinking about something similar to your suggestion but without encryption. I would have the policy service publish a "canonical policy" each time the security policy changes and on regular intervals (daily or hourly). The security policy can be quite complex based on factors such as the user's org. structure position, department, etc. but the canonical policy would always refer to a specific list of users. The "canonical policy" would expire or not.

Comment: @JessieA.Morris (continuation) The problem with this approach is that each consumer would have to implement code to abide by the "canonical policy". The same goes if the "canonical policy" was a user-specific decryption key that expires. Still the svcs would have to check for expiration - the diff is that in my case enforcement would be by checking expiration and checking the user against the authorized list whilst in your case it would be checking expiration and decrypting. So my question still is, is this a good practice? It seems quite original, surely there must be some guidance?!

Answer (score 0):

The solution I settled to is the use of a Policy Service that will act as a mediator between consumers and the Authoritative Service and the Aggregator Service. That way the security policy is implemented in exactly one place: Neither in the Authoritative Service, neither in the Aggregator Service but in the Policy Service.

UI composition will operate in a request/reply fashion and will be mediated by the Policy Service. Furthermore, subscription to the Authoritative Service will be based on roles so only authorized consumers could directly consume sensitive messages. The rule is that those consumers, if exposing data, will need to be accessed through the same Policy Service so that they in turn don't end up being security loopholes.